# How to find duplicate rows from three tables using two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

—oracle sql-

```
Select *
  From Client cl, Contact c, Location l
 Where l.locID     = c.locID 
   and cl.clientID = l.clientID
```

I want to find more than one occurrences(duplicates) using combined columns of locID and clientID

Answer (score 2):

We can use aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT cl.clientID, l.locID
FROM Client cl
INNER JOIN Location l ON l.clientID = cl.clientID
INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.locID = l.locID
GROUP BY cl.clientID, l.locID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Note that I also refactored your query to use explicit joins.

To see all columns, use this version:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT cl.clientID, l.locID,  -- add more columns here
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cl.clientID, l.locID) cnt
    FROM Client cl
    INNER JOIN Location l ON l.clientID = cl.clientID
    INNER JOIN Contact c ON c.locID = l.locID
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: If I want to see the results showing more columns from combined tables, how should I modify above the query?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: after checking results, I have redefine what I really need, for me what i'm looking for is, for same (loc ID and clientID) how many different contact ID's out there?  those are my duplicates if there is different contact id's for same (locID and clientID ) sorry my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the details of the rows using the analytic `COUNT` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT cl.clientID,
         cl.otherClientColumn,
         c.locID,
         c.otherContactColumn,
         l.otherLocationColumn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cl.clientID, c.locID) AS num_duplicates
  From   Client cl
         INNER JOIN Contact c
         ON (cl.clientID = l.clientID)
         INNER JOIN Location l
         ON (l.locID     = c.locID)
)
WHERE  num_duplicates > 1
```